# GRASS v.db.update Concatenate Fields

Tags: grass-gis

I am trying to concatenate two fields into one new field in GRASS, but I am unable to get the syntax to work. Ideally, I would like "FIELD1" and "FIELD2" concatenated together in "FIELD3".  All fields are VARCHARs.  I have tried:

v.db.update layername col=FIELD2 value=FIELD1+FIELD2

using many combinations of +, ||, &, and wrapping in single and double quotes all to no avail. Can someone provide some guidance on the required syntax?

Comment: I should note I am using SQLLite backend, and was able to perform the operation directly in the database using exactly the syntax I expected (using simple || between field names). It would still be interesting to know how to do it in GRASS though, for future reference.

Comment: I have updated the manual with Micha's solution: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/sql.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
v.db.update layername col=FIELD2 qcolumn="FIELD1 || FIELD2"
```

Comment: Thanks Micha! Apparently somewhere in my combination of things, I missed this one. I went back and forth between using 'qcolumn' and 'value' and apparently didn't try all possibilities with both!